# Animate slide overlay and on click hide

Tags: jquery

I have create the panel box and each panel i want to open overlay div. first time it's work fine but when i click another panel it's not working.
Here is the demo:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Abhinav/t7c37grg/)

```
$(this, '.panel').click(function () {
    $('.overlay').animate({
        left: '0px',
    });
});
$('.clbtn').click(function () {
    $('.overlay').stop().hide('4000')
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've narrowed down the issue that you are having.

The problem was that you are hiding the

```
$('.overlay')
```

element but are never making it reappear with:

```
.show()
```

I have attached a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7c37grg/1/) that shows it working more than once.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`$('.overlay').stop().hide('4000')`

try this out:

`$('.overlay').stop().css('left', '-100%');`